# How to get Related Social Media object from Sitefinity in C# (OpenGraphDescription)

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, metadata, sitefinity

I am currently struggling with getting a specific custom field from an object in Sitefinity.

The object's custom field is of type Social media (OpenGraph), meaning it's an o-g meta data description property:

[image]

I tried these:

```
var test = _event.GetRelatedItems<DynamicContent>("OpenGraphDescription");
var test1 = _event.GetRelatedItems<IDataItem>("OpenGraphDescription");
```

But didn't work.

I am, however, able to get Image OG metadata doing:

```
var image = item.GetRelatedItems<Image>("OpenGraphImage").FirstOrDefault();
```

The only difference I see is that I'm getting that one converting it to an internal Sitefinity model (Image).
So maybe I'm missing some model type..

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, the dynamic ItemViewModel is SO MUCH easier to work with than the default API.

```
@{
  var itemVM = new ItemViewModel(yourDynamicItem);
}

<h1>@itemVM.Fields.OpenGraphDescription</h1>
```

You don't need to worry about the types because everything off Fields is dynamic

Comment: I'm working from server side only, because the front-end is separate, built in react. But I could still use ItemViewModel from the back!! This was a lifesaver! Thanks!!